# Custom form: Attachments are half-broken

Tags: custom-form, attachments

I've created a custom edit form, and the attachments functionality is half-broken.  When I click the attach button, it takes me to the attach form and I can browse, select a file, and hit OK.  That all works, and the file is actually attached.  The problem is that it *looks* like it didn't work, because the attach form just clears the file name field and doesn't redirect back to the form.

Has anyone encountered this before? As far as I can tell, this isn't the usual custom form attachments problem.  As I said, I can attach files.  It just looks like I can't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, so after some debugging I found the problem and, even better, the solution.

The OK button on the attach form runs a script called OKAttach(), which features a line towards the end that reads:

```
document.getElementById("idAttachmentsRow").style.display="";
```

All well and good, except that at some point SharePoint sneaked behind your back and did this to the attachments row:

```
<tr id="idAttachmentsRow{generate-id()}">
```

Which means that there is no row with an id of "idAttachmentsRow" and the script breaks.  Simply go in and delete out the generate-id() function and everything's fine again: attachments are attached *and* you're redirected back to the edit form.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a new, empty, element with the appropriate id.  This also seems to restore the "proper" look and feel.